# How to exploit a local file inclusion vulnerability in a Solaris server

Tags: apache, solaris, file-inclusion

I am trying to exploit a local file inclusion vulnerability on a Solaris server for my security course. The server is running Apache2 through CoolStack. What is the file that I need to open? The examples I saw so far all used Linux.

Comment: Welcome to IT Security! I think this question is too broad to be reasonably answerable in the SEI fashion. I would recommend reading through some of the other content on the site and then coming back with something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You should read [LFI to RCE](http://www.exploit-db.com/papers/12992/).  You need to be able to upload a file or populate a log file with a PHP tag and then include this file using the LFI vulnerability.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the great paper but i konw that much, i just dont know what log file i need to populate because it is a solaris server.